# How to play video in only landscape mode in android

Tags: android, video, orientation, landscape

Here I am developing an application which plays video in only landscape mode. I set my activity orientation to "landscape" in AndroidManifest.xml file, and my video is playing very nice but problem is that I hold my device in Landscape mode, when I rotate my device to 180 angle my video playing is upside down (bottom to top). It is not chaging according to that.

Comment: is there any doubt in question to understand ? did i write ant thing wrong.

Comment: please add the min sdk version to ur post

Comment: my min sdk version is "8" and my tetig device is KindleFire Tablet

Answer (score 5):

If you are targeting android version 2.3 or greater then use following in onCreate

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do from manifest file like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Video" android:screenOrientation="userLandscape">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for android 2.2 and below you will have to rotate your content view canvas. Here are two similar questions that suggest something like that..

[How to display Android UI Elements about 180 degrees rotated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866976/how-to-display-android-ui-elements-about-180-degrees-rotated)

[How can you display upside down text with a textview in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558257/how-can-you-display-upside-down-text-with-a-textview-in-android)