# Display TextView data in inverted manner

Tags: android

I an displaying Stopwatch data using TextView as 01:00:45 on the format hh:mm:ss

iPhone has the API to shown the Label in an inverted format which gives the impression of a reflection.

In iPhone , a label is first displayed on the screen. Below the first label , the second label is displayed with the data of the first label in an inverted manner , which gives an impression of a data having reflection.

Is there any API to display the TextView in inverted manner on Android?

[image]

[image]

After referring to the link

- [How can you display upside down text with a textview in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558257/how-can-you-display-upside-down-text-with-a-textview-in-android)                                                                                                                                                                            & using the sample canvas code for rotation using 180 , I am getting the inverted text in green colour(displayed above) . But my requirement is to display a reflection , which is actually the text displayed in red colour.

Kindly provide your inputs/sample code.

Comment: I wonder if you could capture the drawing cache for the text view and then render it inverted in a custom view below it using canvas calls.

Comment: kindly help if anyone aware of , still not able to develop the required reflection

Answer (score 0):

1)To display inverted text with respect to x-axis

`android:rotationX="180"`

(add this in the xml file within the respective element)

2)To display inverted text with respect to y-axis

`android:rotationY="180"`

(add this in the xml file within the respective element)