# How to move seekbar from right to left?

Tags: android, xml, android-seekbar

This is the seekbar that I have used in my XML. I want to move the seekbar from right to left as per my requirement but not able to do this. Can anybody help me in this?

```
<SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar_luminosite"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:max="30"
                android:maxWidth="15dp"
                android:maxHeight="13dp"
                android:minWidth="15dp"
                android:minHeight="15dp"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar"
                android:splitTrack="false"
                android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231609/reverse-seekbar-right-to-left-colour

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617187/android-seekbar-flipped-horizontally) it will works

Comment: it worked @MayankSharma...Thanks