# Seekbar min value 100 and max 0 Android

Tags: android, android-seekbar, android-vertical-seekbar

A vertical seekbar  has minimum value 0 and maximum value 1000. Is it possible that at the bottom the seekbar min progress is 1000 and when at top level it becomes 0. The current seekbar range is

```
seekBarTop.setProgress(0);
seekBarTop.incrementProgressBy(10);
seekBarTop.setMax(1000);
```

Comment: Please clarify your question a little bit more..

Comment: Check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617187/android-seekbar-flipped-horizontally It might helps you.

Comment: You can just set rotation to 90, wouldn't that work for you?

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `SeekBar extend ProgressBar` and by definition [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) is *Visual indicator of progress in some operation*. So it is just a partition used to show current progress/status..

As you have defined `setProgress(0)` and `setMax(1000)` it creates a seekbar with 100 partition with 10 increments...So I would suggest you to get current progress, and reduce it by 1000 `(1000 - value)` to get your final value *(you can create a method return final value)*.....this will show your progress from `1000----0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
     SeekBar sbTolerance = findViewById(R.id.sbTolerance);



    sbTolerance.setMax(100);

 sbTolerance.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                int j = 100 - i;
                Toast.makeText(AlertSetting.this, ""+j, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                if(seekBar.getProgress()==0||seekBar.getProgress()==100)
                    enableManualButton();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```