# Right to left progress bar with text

Tags: android, canvas, android-progressbar

I need a progress bar displaying progress from right to left or from left to right depending on variable. I have also text in the middle of the bar. For all that, I am using a custom class. For rotating the bar, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877823/right-to-left-progressbar) thread but somehow either the text is not displayed, or it is rotated, or everything disappears from the view...

**Code without rotation:**

```
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // draw text
    }
```

I have a property `positive` telling whether to start from left or from right. It would be easy, if I didn't had the text, I would simply call `setRotation()` somewhere in the code, but now I am trying to rotate the canvas and I can't manage it to bring everything in the correct order. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it out. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572572/rotate-text-in-canvas) thread, I ended up with the following code:

```
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    if(!positive) {
        int cx = this.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        int cy = this.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
        canvas.scale(-1f, 1f, cx, cy);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
    // draw text
}
```

I have no idea why rotation doesn't work for me but the `scale` method works fine.