# Rotate text and icons of an android app

Tags: java, android

My question is how can I modify this code (the selected method):

https://github.com/dudeofawesome/CardboardHome/blob/master/app/src/main/java/dudeofawesome/cardboardhome/Launcher.java#L721

so the text (name of the app like in the photo and icons) are rotated

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: try checking out matrix rotations    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166917/android-how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-on-a-center-point

Comment: I don't know where they are thanks

Comment: nothing is rotated on your image

Comment: I just wont to flip the text so it looks upside down

Comment: I don't want animations

Answer (score 0):

Try the method [Canvas.drawTextOnPath](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawTextOnPath(java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Path,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)), with a path that goes along the line you want but from right to left, instead of left to right, which would draw the text as you have it already. The picture doesn't show any rotation, so it's unclear what you want your end result to look like.

Or try [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558257/how-can-you-display-upside-down-text-with-a-textview-in-android)

Disclaimer: I only used it once to make curved text by specifying two paths, separate for the top and bottom. It may also be more of what you want:

[image]